# How to smoothly animate hiding of sidebar which effects size of other areas

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions

I have a screen with 3 horizontally aligned main areas:

[image]

The sidebar (1) can be collapsed/hidden (to the left). When hidden, the freed-up space shall be given to the visualization (3) whilst the menus width (2) stays the same.

ATM I'm aligning the content like this:

- **Parent container of (1), (2) & (3):** `display: flex`
- **(1):** `width: 260px;`
- **(2):** `width: 293px;`
- **(3):** `flex: 1;`

When collapsed, I simply set `width: 0` for the sidebar.

I know that I could simply animate/transition the `width` change or go about it by changing and animating/transition the `left` property or play with margins etc. but all those solutions I can think of trigger the browsers layout step (changing `width`, `left`, `margin`, ...) which I'd like to prevent since that leads to poor animation performance as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/).

Ideally I'd like to stay with CSS transitions of properties which only trigger the browsers compose step like `translate` etc.

Unfortunately I can't think of a way to only use those "good" CSS properties and also meet my goal of redistributing the freed-up space from the hidden sidebar to the visualization (3).

Is it even possible to hide the sidebar animated to the left without triggering a re-layout but still redistribute the freed-up space? If not, how can this still be done performantly?

I imagine that this is a pretty common use case in web development, so links to according literature, blogs etc. are welcome as well!

I found a lot of examples on the web regarding animated hiding of sidebars but they either animate the `width` property or don't redistribute the freed up space to the remaining visible content (e.g. sidebars which are simply shown "above" the main content etc.), so none of the examples I found so far actually meet my described goals...

Comment: Hello, this is effect you want replicate ?https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapse_sidebar.asp

Comment: @ErnestoGonzalezMartin They animate the `width` of the sidebar which is really bad for performance since it causes the browser to re-layout the whole page (see [this link](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/)) & which I'd like to prevent as (maybe badly) described in my question.

Comment: Hello, why you have not mentioned the **absolute OR fixed** position to the sidebar and set its coordinate to **left:0;** then use translate?

Comment: @Moayad Because that won't redistribute the freed up space on the visualization (area 3) without animating other "bad" properties like width etc, as explained in the question.

Comment: The two requirements of 1) redistributing freed-up space, and 2) don't change `width` properties seem at odds with one another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the following `HTML`,`JS`,`CSS` snippet. You could change the actual widths of the elements to exactly match the ones you need.

Manipulating the `width` of the sidebar is not a problem. Performance is, as explained in the [link](https://css-tricks.com/emulating-css-timing-functions-javascript/) you provided. On the finishing lines of this article it is written:

> Performance matters to users. Web developers need to build apps that
> react quickly and render smoothly. Google performance guru Paul Lewis
> is here to help you destroy jank and create web apps that maintain 60
> frames per second performance. You'll leave this course with the tools
> you need to profile apps and identify the causes of jank. You'll
> explore the browser's rendering pipeline and uncover patterns that
> make it easy to build performant apps.

So you could re-create the logic of the below example by using `Javascript` `requestAnimationFrame` as shown [here](https://css-tricks.com/emulating-css-timing-functions-javascript/).

```js
const side = document.querySelector('.side');
const sideToggle = document.querySelector('.sideToggle');
const main = document.querySelector('.main');
sideToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (!sideToggle.classList.contains('active')) {
    sideToggle.classList.add('active');
  } else {
    sideToggle.classList.remove('active');
  }

  if (!main.classList.contains('full')) {
    main.classList.add('full');
  } else {
    main.classList.remove('full');
  }
  if (!side.classList.contains('hidden')) {
    side.classList.add('hidden');
  } else {
    side.classList.remove('hidden');
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: space-evenly;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
}

.side {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: space-evenly;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background: #000;
  padding: 0;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: width 1s linear;
}

.side a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  height: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.side a:hover {
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
}

.side.hidden {
  width: 0;
  transition: width 1s linear;
}

.sideToggle {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  position: fixed;
  right: .75rem;
  bottom: .75rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1001;
}

.sideToggle:after {
  content: "\2630";
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.sideToggle.active:after {
  content: "\00D7";
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 1.75rem;
}

.main {
  background: red;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: width 1s linear;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: space-evenly;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.main.full {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 1s linear;
}

.left {
  width: 15rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.right {
  width: calc(100% - 15rem);
  background: indigo;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="side">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Page 1</a>
    <a href="#">Page 2</a>
    <a href="#">Page 3</a>
  </div>
  <span class="sideToggle active"></span>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="left">
        this width is ment to be static
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        this width is ment to be dynamic 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is another possible way by using mostly `translateX` and without changing the `width` of the sidebar.

```js
const side = document.querySelector('.side');
const sideToggle = document.querySelector('.sideToggle');
const main = document.querySelector('.main');
sideToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (!sideToggle.classList.contains('active')) {
    sideToggle.classList.add('active');
  } else {
    sideToggle.classList.remove('active');
  }

  if (!main.classList.contains('full')) {
    main.classList.add('full');
  } else {
    main.classList.remove('full');
  }
  if (!side.classList.contains('hidden')) {
    side.classList.add('hidden');
  } else {
    side.classList.remove('hidden');
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: space-evenly;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
}

.side {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: space-evenly;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background: #000;
  padding: 0;
  width: 7rem;
  transform: translateX(0);
  height: 100vh;
  transition: transform 1s linear, z-index 1s linear;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  will-change: transform, z-index;
}

.side a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  height: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.side a:hover {
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
}

.side.hidden {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform 1s linear, z-index 1s linear;
  z-index: -1;
}

.sideToggle {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  position: fixed;
  right: .75rem;
  bottom: .75rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1001;
}

.sideToggle:after {
  content: "\2630";
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.sideToggle.active:after {
  content: "\00D7";
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 1.75rem;
}

.main {
  background: red;
  width: calc(100% - 7rem);
  height: 100vh;
  transition: transform 1s linear, width 1s linear;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: space-evenly;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(7rem);
  position: absolute;
  will-change: transform, width;
}

.main.full {
  transform: translateX(0);
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform 1s linear, width 1s linear;
}

.main .left,
.main.full .left {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  width: 15rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.right {
  flex-grow: 2;
  flex-shrink: 2;
  width: calc(100% - 15rem);
  background: indigo;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="side">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Page 1</a>
    <a href="#">Page 2</a>
    <a href="#">Page 3</a>
  </div>
  <span class="sideToggle active"></span>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="left">
      this width is ment to be static
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      this width is ment to be dynamic
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: By using translateX you take advantage of GPU rendering so the animation is 60FPS througout the duration of the animation..!!

Answer (score 0):

Althought the solution of user2560539 is nice, it did not suffice my requirements because with a lot of elements in the content area, the manipulation of the sidebar width leads definitely to a performance problem.

The issue is that as soon as you start transforming geometrical or positional properties (width, height, margin, padding, top, left, bottom, right, etc.) the browser starts to recalculate the layout again and again for every frame during the animation. You can see this in the performance tab of Chrome or Firefox as "Layout Shift". This is super laggy as soon as your DOM includes more than a few nodes.

Transformations (translations, rotations, skews, etc.) are much faster because the browser does not need to calculate all values regarding geometry and position over and over again. The browser calculates everything on a per pixel basis.

So I came up with another solution. What I did is to use the fast

```
transform: scaleX(1.1); //e.g. 1920px / 1745px
```

CSS property to enlarge the content area. The factor 1.1 is calculated by the width of the full content area (no sidebar visible) divided by the compressed content area (sidebar visible).

With this in mind you can use a simple translation animation to translate the sidebar and to scale the content area. Here is a codepen [slightly stolen from user2560539, thank you :) ]:

https://codepen.io/enne87/pen/MWBaOrp

Of course the content is distorted since scaleX does not only scale the content wrapper, but also all its child elements. If this is a problem for you, you can add a CSS class to the distorted elements which holds the inverse of the scaleX operation:

```
.make-thinner-initally {
    transform: scaleX(0.9088); //e.g. 1745px / 1920px
}
```

Add this class to the elements as soon as the animation begins and remove it after the animation ends.

By the way, [Google Calendar](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r) uses a very similar approach when you expand / collapse the left side bar.